# Webview mudando o url conforme o dia

Tags: android

Fiz um blog , para usar somente neste app , ele é sobre liturgia , e a cada dia tem uma liturgia , então são 365 liturgias , se eu for colocar 365 activity o app vai ficar muito pesado , então pensei em colocar só uma activity com webview , queria saber se tem como eu mudar somente o link do webview a cada dia , por exemplo , hoje é o dia 228 do ano então ele vai exibir um url , amanhã será o dia 229 então ele exibirá outro url , só mudando os url's

Segue abaixo meu webview

```
    String url = "https://paroquiasaoroqueblog.wordpress.com/228-2/";
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewnsCarmo);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    wv.loadUrl(url);
    wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

obs : o 2 no link do webview é desconsiderado pois é gerado automaticamente pelo blog ao publicar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode concatenar o atual dia do ano na sua URL usando a classe [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

Exemplo:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String url = "https://paroquiasaoroqueblog.wordpress.com/" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + "-2/";
```